# C++ Linker error in Netbeans using Mingw64

Tags: netbeans, linker, mingw

I am using Netbeans and Mingw. My work needs to use FFTW and NIHCL library, and I have already put `liblfftwlib.a` and `liblnihcllib.a` in `Properties/Linker/Libraries`. I have also put directory of these static libraries in Additional Library Directories. However, when I compiled, an error

> "collect2.exe: error: ld returned 116 exit status"

occurred. What should I do to fix this error? Should I add something in Additional Options?

Comment: This is my setting: http://imgur.com/5ByKI4w

Comment: To get help with a failing linkage you need to post the failing linkage command, and all the error messages that result from it. `collect2.exe: error: ld returned 116 exit status` is just the toolchain's farewell summary, after the linker command and its errors have already
been printed. Post the final `g++ ...` command line that appears in the Netbeans build log (in the Output pane), and everything that follows it. Include this information directly in your question.

Comment: Thank you so much Mike Kinghan. I have just found that the problem was because of my static libraries. I am rebuilding those two static libraries. Hope it works well!